# PHPStorm: JS Language Injection with custom tags inside template

Tags: phpstorm

In needing html templates with embedded javascript on a PHP project I was not satisfied with any solutions I found, so, with Lodash and some regex I created the following solution :

Template:

```
<script id="profile_greeting" type="text/template">
    <h1>Hello</h1><br>
    My name is <b><@=this.name@></b><br>
    <@ var today = "" + new Date(); @>
    The date is : <@= today @>
</script>
```

Lodash settings :

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\<\@\=([\s\S]+?)\@\>/g,
    escape: /\<\@\-([\s\S]+?)\@\>/g,
    evaluate: /\<\@([\s\S]+?)\@\>/g
};
```

Question:

How do I setup PHPStorm to treat any code inside <@ @> and <@= @> as Javascript (syntax highlight, code completion, etc) while treating the outside as HTML ?

Note:

Code inside  should be treated as HTML, and <@ @> pieces should *only* be treated as javascript when inside this type of  tag.

Answer (score 3):

Press `Alt+F7` and go to `Language Injections` and create a new injection that is customized to your wishes.

Maybe [**this**](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/language-injection-settings-generic-javascript.html) can help.

**Edit:**

I made a [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3bul2) with the regexp to match your wishes (`/<@((?:\s|.)*?)@>/gm`).
Only trouble is how it should be fed to PHPStorm...

Comment: This is what I tried for several hours before I asked the question. However, I cannot get it to work. At the time, this is what I came up with (obviously does not work) : http://puu.sh/kuLMa/125327746e.png

Comment: @JoaoCarlos okay, i'm going to try and fix it.
So, if you enter `<@` it must inject JS until `@>` except the first `=`?

Comment: i must go now, i'll try to help tomorrow

Comment: anything inside <@ and @> is JS, anything inside <@= @> is also JS but as straight evaluation like a PHP <?php echo 'bla'; ?> can be shortened with <?='bla'?>

Comment: @JoaoCarlos and you want the <@ and @> to be removed?

Comment: Removed how? The code is inside those tags, just like PHP.

Comment: I never heard of <@ before so i assumed it wasnt correct syntax and should be replaced/removed, am i correct?

Comment: In the post it explains that I created it :)

Comment: Sorry, i got stuck too. You can always select string and press alt+enter and manually inject JS.

Comment: Due to the awesomeness of stackoverflow your answer was awarded the bounty, not because it was correct but because it was the only one haha. Free rep HoopHoop!

Comment: @JoaoCarlos this `<@((?:\s|.)*?)@>` matches everything between the tags.
Only need to find out how to use PHPstorm language injection settings :)

Comment: LOL, didn't see that while i was researching this regexp

Comment: Like I said, I created the regex rules for it. My problem is actually getting PHPStorm to understand them.

Comment: @JoaoCarlos PHPstorm language injections don't use regexp, they use BRiCS, the most documentation-free thing i have ever (not) seen.
If you can find a link that explains BRiCS than you have won the internets.

Comment: @JoaoCarlos have you found a solution since then?